# Add text to PDF

Tags: matlab, pdf

I've got an exported version of a MATLAB diagram, similar to the one below. The problem is, that there are no axis captions. It's not possible to export the file again from MATLAB. I need to edit the PDF programmatically and edit about 100 diagrams, all with the same axis positions.

Is there a clean and fast way to paste the Strings **X** and **Y** at the corresponding positions in the pdf based on a batch process?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a PDF file with the captions. Add that as a background with to the PDF files with [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/).

Answer (score 0):

if know how to use LaTeX, the [pstool package](http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/pstool/pstool.pdf) can bring you far on this on, including replacing labels (or actually any text on an eps figure) with TeX symbolic expressions. Neat if you're already working in LaTeX.